# Program executes next task right away

Tags: c#

If player reaches level 2, then it right away tries "if level == 2". What I should change? If you get level up, then you click just "ok" and nothing will pop up. Right now if you get level up, it will try to Level up you again if you click "Ok" on the "levelup" messagebox text.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gold > 249)
        {
            gold -= 250;
            label3.Text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString();
            level++;
            label4.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(levelup);
        }
        else
        {
            int needed = 250;
            MessageBox.Show("Not enough to level up! You need: " + needed + " Gold");
        }
        if (level == 2)
        {
            button4.Text = "Level Up! (350 Gold)";
            if (gold > 349)
            {
                gold -= 350;
                label3.Text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString();
                level++;
                label4.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(levelup);
            }
            else
            {
                int needed = 350;
                MessageBox.Show("Not enough to level up! You need: " + needed + " Gold");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have 2 pieces of code in your button click.  so first part one fires when that's ready  part 2 fires. and also part 1 will always fire even if you are lvl 2 because you only check for gold there. So check for lvl there also i would say

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it by first checking for the highest lvl and then go down.
In the second part i also added "if (level == 1)" else it would always fire if there is more gold than 249. "so better check for lvl there also"

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (level == 2)
    {
        button4.Text = "Level Up! (350 Gold)";
        if (gold > 349)
        {
            gold -= 350;
            label3.Text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString();
            level++;
            label4.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(levelup);
        }
        else
        {
            int needed = 350;
            MessageBox.Show("Not enough to level up! You need: " + needed + " Gold");
        }
    }

    else if (level == 1)
    {
        if (gold > 249)
        {
            gold -= 250;
            label3.Text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString();
            level++;
            label4.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(levelup);
        }
        else
        {
            int needed = 250;
            MessageBox.Show("Not enough to level up! You need: " + needed + " Gold");
        }
    }
}
```